# How to read lua table in C

Tags: c, lua, lua-table

I have a table as follows:

```
ARQtable = 
{
    120,  250,  400,  500,  730,
    790,  810,  935,  950,  999,

}
```

I'm trying to read the table in lua using c. need to apply the values that will be made in function `ARQSystem-> arqtable`

But while reading the table I'm having error of: `PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a nil value)`

My code is as follows:

```
void read_table(void){
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    int val = 2000, i = 0;
    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "tables.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        ShowError("Error reading 'tables.lua'\n");
        return;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "ARQtable");
    if (lua_type(L, -1) == LUA_TTABLE) {
        for (i = 0; i < val; i++) {
            lua_pushnumber(L, i);
            lua_gettable(L, -2);
            ARQSystem->arqtable[i] = lua_isnumber(L, -1);
            lua_settop(L, -2);
        }
    }
    lua_close(L);
    printf("Read Table complete.\n");

}
```

I wanted to know why it's happening this error in reading, am new to the lua I'm still learning, someone to help me?

Comment: _Please_ use one of the `LUA_T*` constants and not a magic number (`5`) in the `lua_type` if statement.

Comment: Your `for`-loop lacks the braces.  BTW, `lua_close` should not be inside it.

Comment: OK, I did the fixes cited, but the panic error continues.

Comment: Please update the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lua_getglobal(L,"ARQtable")` instead of `lua_getfield(L,-1,"ARQtable")`.

The error comes from trying to get a field from a table, when there is none on the stack at that moment.

Comment: Using `lua_getglobal` the panic is gone, but still crash occurs.

Comment: @Chozie - `lua_getglobal` has two arguments, not three

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff Excuse me, error when editing the code. But in my tool he's with 2 arguments.